# Can't run ng serve within Angular project

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

So I am trying to serve or build my Angular application. I have always found it difficult to use the angular CLI commands. Every time I run `ng serve` or `npm run ng serve`.

I get the error "The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found."

I don't understand what it means by this and don't really want to update my Angular to a different version.

I have tried npm uninstall, npm install, installing the CLI and uninstalling the CLI. All of which provide feedback which doesn't make a huge amount of sense to me.

I am running these commands in the src folder of my angular project and my dependencies look like this:

```
"@angular/animations": "^4.4.7",
"@angular/common": "^4.4.7",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.4.7",
"@angular/core": "^4.4.7",
"@angular/forms": "^4.4.7",
"@angular/http": "^4.4.7",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.7",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.7",
"@angular/router": "^4.4.7",
"@ngui/datetime-picker": "^0.16.2",
"angular": "^1.7.5",
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should run it in you project main folder not in src/

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are trying to run the command from the wrong location. You should run 'ng serve' from projects directory.

So, basically you should follow below steps:

1. ng new my-project
2. cd my-project
3. ng serve

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

This error means you are not in the correct folder; a folder containing a project definition.

Run `ng serve` in the **parent** folder of your `src` folder